# Updating ADFv2 pipeline after creating a trigger against it

Tags: azure-data-factory

If I have a pipeline against which I have created a trigger (say TumblingWindow type) , at some stage if I update the pipeline, will the subsequent execution of the trigger refer to the new pipeline? Or it will keep using the version of the pipeline which was there when the trigger was created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New pipeline runs will use the new version of the pipeline, no matter if the run comes from a Manual run or a trigger run.

If there are InProgress Pipeline runs, those will continue running with the same version as they started.